# Программа "Калькулятор". Пишет что переменные dEl, proiz,raz,sum не определены. Вот код:

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def chisla(a,oper,b):

   if oper in ("+","-","*","/"):

 if oper == "+":
   sum = a + b

 if oper == "-":
   raz = a - b

 if oper == "*":
   proiz = a * b

 if  oper == "/":
   if b == 0:
     print("I can't do it.")
   else:  
     dEl = a / b

   else:
     print("Error. Your input is wrong.")

 while True:
  a = float(input("Input 1 number: "))
  oper = str(input("Input operation: "))
  b = float(input("Input 2 number: "))

  chisla(a,oper,b)

  if oper == "+":
   print(sum)

  if oper == "-":
   print(raz)

  if oper == "*":
   print(proiz)

  if  oper == "/":
   print(dEl)
```

Comment: Вы про область видимости что-нибудь знаете?

Comment: @DmitryErohin нет

Comment: @Михаил настало время исправлять этот недочет :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def chisla(a,oper,b):

   if oper in ("+","-","*","/"):

        if oper == "+": return a + b

        if oper == "-": return a - b

        if oper == "*": return a * b

        if  oper == "/":    
            if b == 0:
                return None
            return a / b


while True:   
      a = float(input("Input 1 number: "))   
      oper = str(input("Input operation: "))   
      b = float(input("Input 2 number: "))

      print(chisla(a,oper,b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Антивандальный калькулятор (:

```
def get_number(msg):
    try:
        num = float(input(msg))
    except ValueError:
        print('Numbers only allowed!')
        return None
    return num

while True:
    x = y = op = None
    while x is None:
        x = get_number('Enter first number: ')
    while y is None:
        y = get_number('Enter second number: ')
    while op not in ('+', '-', '*', '/'):
        print('Allowed operations: "+", "-", "*", "/"')
        op = input('Enter operation: ')
    try:
        result = eval('{0}{2}{1}'.format(x, y, op))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('Zero division prohibited!\n')
        continue
    print(result, '\n')
```